# Comparing JSON array with Mongo array document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Currently I have a mongoose model 'Event' that stores a list of UUIDs as participants that reference another model 'User'

```
.
participants: [{
        _id: false,
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        tickets: {
            type: Number,
            min: 0,
        },
    }],

winners: [{
           type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User'
}], 
.
.
```

Now I receive a request with the following JSON data to update my winners

```
{
"winners": [
        "5f61132da98bac2a98487d79",
        "5f611378a98bac2a98487d7a",
        "5f611378a98bac2a98487d77"
]}
```

Is there a way to compare this array with participant field of that model and only allow entry of user ids that are participants? For example

```
const event = await Event.findOne({_id: _id}, 'participants.id -_id');
console.log(event.participants);

Output:
[
    { id: 5f61132da98bac2a98487d79 },
    { id: 5f611378a98bac2a98487d7a },
    { id: 5f6113b1a98bac2a98487d7b }
]

console.log(req.body.rewards);
[
  '5f61132da98bac2a98487d79',
  '5f611378a98bac2a98487d7a',
  '5f611378a98bac2a98487d77'
]
```

Clearly the last UUID is not matching (is not a participant) so should be discarded and other two remaining should be updated in winners field. JSON object can be made flexible if needed.

Comment: Does https://mongoplayground.net/p/P31QgVsOvjf this help you?

Answer (score 0):

Using aggregation framework does not really help me on this problem, and it might be very costly to project specific elements for a single document only. A work around solution would be using arrays.

```
const event = await Event.findOne({
                _id: _eventId,
                rewards: { $elemMatch: { _id: _rewardId }}
            }, 'participants.id -_id');

const allParticipants = []

(event.participants).forEach((item) => {
        allParticipants.push(item.id.toString());
    });

const validIds = (req.body.winners).filter(item => allParticipants.includes(item));
```

This will check for arrays using includes and filter and return matching array item from the request and participants in the event.